# jQuery Text field containing math operator

Tags: jquery, math, operators

I have several text fields, and the value of these fields can be "4", "-2", "10", etc.

I would like to retrieve this value and make the corresponding mathematical operation:

```
var price = 50;
var value = $ ( "# myTextField").val(); //e.g value = "+50"
var finalprice = price + value

alert(finalprice)
```

But, of course it doesnt work and only display "50+50". Could you please help me so it can also work if my value was -30 ? Thanks a lot

**EDIT: Sorry but you didn't understand me:
I need to keep the math operator of my text field (- or +) so I can't convert my string into an Integer.**

Comment: Use var value = parse.int($ ( "# myTextField").val());

Comment: Tl;Dr `Number($( "#myTextField").val());`

Answer (score 2):

you need to parse string to an integer:

```
var value = parseInt($("#myTextField").val(), 10);
```

Comment: Thx for the radix ;)

Comment: Watch the spaces `"#myTextField"` !== `"# myTextField"`

Comment: No, I don't want to convert my string in Int, because the value contains the math operator I need (+10 or -4)

Comment: If u convert -10 to  parseInt("-10") it will return -10 it will  not make 10

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the string as integer - `parseInt()`
https://jsfiddle.net/wk4a5vm2/1/

If you want to get string with an operator you should use `eval()`
https://jsfiddle.net/wk4a5vm2/4/